# OCR input format for tensorflow model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, ocr

I am trying to build a ocr model using tensorflow 2.0. So I want to start with CNN. I know that I can give image in array format to the model. But I am not able to understand how can I give input format for my labels for training the model. Label length is 10 and it can contain any 4 alphabets and 6 numbers. I was looking for the solution on google and found out https://github.com/JackonYang/captcha-tensorflow/blob/master/captcha-solver-tf2-4digits-AlexNet-98.8.ipynb. But here they only have digits in label but my label has characters also. Can anybody please throw some light on this?

Comment: The link you posted is a good starting point. They use `N_LABELS = 10` and `D = 4`. You should try to use `N_LABELS = 10` since you have 6+4 possible outcomes and `D = 10` since the length of the thing you are trying to read is that.

Comment: Yeah. I'm concern with  this line of code cell number 6 labels.append(np.array([np.array(to_categorical(int(i), N_LABELS)) for i in label])).